# GNU Parallel facing silent exit and invalid option error

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, redhat, gnu, gnu-parallel

I tried performing the full installation from: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

The installation was successful. It's working well when installed on Mac OS but on Amazon Linux (RHEL64) I am facing below issues:

1. On running just `parallel` the command exits silently.

   ```
   dev-dsk % parallel
   dev-dsk %
   ```
2. On running **any** command even `parallel --version` gives following error:

   ```
   dev-dsk % parallel --version                                               
   parallel: invalid option -- '-'
   parallel [OPTIONS] command -- arguments
       for each argument, run command with argument, in parallel
   parallel [OPTIONS] -- commands
       run specified commands in parallel
   ```

   Same error with running `parallel --gnu`.

IMO, there is no conflict with **NO** conflict with **Tollef's** parallel of moreutils package as moreutils doesn't exit on my machine.

Please help me understanding how to make GNU Parallel work on RHEL64?

Comment: So `whereis parallel` ? `hash parallel`? `file $(hash parallel)` ? `stat $(hash parallel)`?

Comment: It's GNU Parallel: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Comment: So what is the problem? What is your question? Obviously it's not. Or it's an old version. Or you made an error. Or PATH is set to something strange. Or `parallel` is a shell builtin. Or a function. Or an alias. `man parallel` proves that you have man parallel. Not exeuctable. Not that you are running that executable. I don't believe it proves anything. `whereis parallel` should give you the full path to parallel exeuctable. Then you can `cmp .. ..` the executable with the one you compiled in your compile directory to see it's the same. For example.

Comment: @Kamil: The ask is to make it work. I just did an installation and no path change and etc. It's working fine on my MAC using same installation. But not working on my RHEL64 machine. Running `whereis parallel` helped me find a working solution. Thanks!

Comment: The output you get is exactly the output Tollef's `parallel` gives. So somewhere in your `$PATH` you have that installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure why it was not working. In my system there was just one executable named parallel in system path, but still it was not getting detected.

**But anyway, I was able to fix it as below**:

1. Run `whereis parallel`. This gives all the paths where executables named **parallel** is present. For my case there was just one path `/usr/local/bin/parallel`. Running using this path works just fine.
2. You can add an alias for this in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file like `alias parallel='/usr/local/bin/parallel'`

And now `parallel` works like charm.

```
dev-dsk % parallel --version         
GNU parallel 20190322
Copyright (C) 2007-2019 Ole Tange and Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
GNU parallel comes with no warranty.
```